# onBillingSetupFinished not called

Tags: android, in-app-purchase

After correctly configuring the BillingClient as in the documentation onBillingSetupFinished is not called.

```
 //...

 billingClient = BillingClient.newBuilder(this)
                .setListener(purchaseUpdateListener)
                .enablePendingPurchases()
                .build();

       
        //billingClient != null

        billingClient.startConnection(new BillingClientStateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onBillingSetupFinished(BillingResult billingResult) {

              //This is not called


            }
            @Override
            public void onBillingServiceDisconnected() {

                //This is not called
            }



        });

  //...
```

It only happens on some devices.

Answer (score 0):

Some Chinese devices, like the one I have (BV9900). They have a clean button when you press and hold home that not only closes all apps, but also completely closes all apps and services, including Google's.
By preventing any app from running in the background, this disables in-app purchases. The solution in this case is to open the Play Store in Intent to start the services again.